# Laravel pivot table create association once, then update

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

User:

```
userID
...
```

Lesson:

```
lessonID
...
```

Users_Lessons_Status (which acts as a pivot table and holds other information):

```
userID references User.userID
lessonID references Lessons.lessonID
latestSectionID
percentComplete
```

What I want to do is, for each user, for each lesson, there should be a row in the pivot table that tells how much the user has completed in that lesson and what their latest section ID was. That is, there should be a unique pair with `userID` and `lessonID` (primary keys?).

I have set up my models like so:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

...


    public function lessonStatuses() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Lesson', 'users_lessons_status', 'lessonID', 'userID')->withPivot('latestSectionID', 'percentComplete');
    }

}

<?

class Lesson extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'lessons';
protected $primaryKey = 'lessonID';

public function userStatuses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_lessons_status', 'userID', 'lessonID');
}


}

?>
```

My current route looks like this:

```
Route::post('dbm/users/setLatestSectionID', function() {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $user = User::find(Input::get('userID'));
        $lesson = Lesson::find(Input::get('lessonID'));
        $us = $user->lessonStatuses(); 
        $us->attach($lesson->lessonID, 
            ["latestSectionID" => Input::get('latestSectionID'), "percentComplete" => Input::get('percentComplete')] );
    }
});
```

This works, however, it creates a new row every time I update it for the same `userID` and `lessonID`, so the pair is no longer unique. Which methods should I use for this purpose? I tried both `save()`, `attach()` and `push()` in the documentation but I'm not sure which one to use here.

**Edit**: to clarify, the resulting table should look something like this:

```
id|userID|lessonID|latestSectionID|percentComplete
1    1      1             X             Y
2    1      2        
3    1      3         
4    2      1          
5    3      1
6    3      2
....
```

**Edit 2**: Fixed the `User->belongsToMany()` method and added the `withPivot` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like a bug, nevertheless you can do this:

```
...->sync([$id], false); // detaching set to false, so it will only insert new rows, skip existing and won't detach anything
```

edit:
As said in comment - it will not work for you, as you want to set pivot data.
So basically there is no method to do this at the moment, but something like this should do:

```
// belongsToMany.php
public function attachOrUpdate($id, array $attributes = array(), $touch = true)
{
    if ($id instanceof Model) $id = $id->getKey();

    if ( ! $this->allRelatedIds()->contains($id)) // getRelatedIds() in prior to v5.4
    {
        return $this->attach($id, $attributes, $touch); 
    }
    else if ( ! empty($attributes))
    {
        return $this->updateExistingPivot($id, $attributes, $touch);
    }
}
```

I'm gonna test it and if it passes, send a pull request to 4.1

Comment: Do you mean like this:
`$us->sync($lesson->lessonID, ["latestSectionID" => Input::get('latestSectionID'), "percentComplete" => Input::get('percentComplete')], false );`?
For some reason it says that argument 1 is a string and not an array.

Comment: It should be `$us->sync([$lesson->lessonID, ["latestSectionID" => ...`

Comment: user2.. nope, sync doesn't accepts attributes. pg-robban I didn't notice you were up to updating (or creating) pivot data. Updated my answer.

Comment: @decoz the manual says it does, I remember there wasn't this option before.

Comment: It works, I will mark this as answered even though I don't like tinkering with the source files. Thank you.
Edit: It seems like for user with ID 2 it will set the lessonID to 2 rather than userID2. I assume this is just something I messed up with my models.

Comment: Any updates on your pull request @JarekTkaczyk? I'd like a `attachOrUpdate` function in Laravel, can't find something similar in version 5.2.

Comment: If you are using Laravel 5.4, the getRelatedIds function is now called allRelatedIds, so you'll need to alter the function to use that instead.

Comment: @SarahKemp true, thanks, edited. That's the curse of Laravel - changing public interfaces in a way that doesn't give pretty much any value, yet causes a lot of BC breaking issues for consumers

Answer (score 5):

I faced this recently and fixed it in this way:

Use `updateExistingPivot` first and check the result , if result is `1` it means there were row with the same `userID` and `lessonID` and it's been updated successfully, otherwise, if result is `0` it means there were no rows with this `userID` and `lessonID`, so you can attach it in order to create new row

```
    $update_result = $us->updateExistingPivot($lesson->lessonID, 
            ["latestSectionID" => Input::get('latestSectionID'), "percentComplete" => Input::get('percentComplete')] );
    if($update_result == 0) {
        $us->attach($lesson->lessonID, 
            ["latestSectionID" => Input::get('latestSectionID'), "percentComplete" => Input::get('percentComplete')] );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `updateExistingPivot()`.

Update your code to use

```
    $us->updateExistingPivot($lesson->lessonID, 
        ["latestSectionID" => Input::get('latestSectionID'), "percentComplete" => Input::get('percentComplete')], true );
```

The last parameter will update the timestamps for all related models.  If not, you can remove or set to false.

If you want to attach only when a record doesn't exist, you could do something like this...

```
Route::post('dbm/users/setLatestSectionID', function() {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $user = User::find(Input::get('userID'));

        $lesson = [
            "latestSectionID" => Input::get('latestSectionID'), 
            "percentComplete" => Input::get('percentComplete')
        ];

        $num_lessons = $user->lessonStatuses()->where('id', Input::get('lessonID'))->count();

        if($num_lessons == 0) {
            $user->attach($lesson->lessonID, $lesson);
        } else {
            $user->updateExistingPivot($lesson->lessonID, $lesson);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It seems like this doesn't create the rows in the table.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that's exactly what you wanted.  You want to create one, unless one already exists, in which case you want to update?

Comment: You understood me correctly, but maybe I need to clarify: the current `attach()` method that I have now creates the row when it doesn't exist. However, on subsequent calls, it creates additional rows instead of updating existing ones. I think what you mean is that I need to create the association first and then call `updateExistingPivot`, right?

Comment: I think that would be the better route to go because once you get to the `dbm/users/setLatestSectionID` route, I would assume a section has already been created for the lesson.  I updated the answer though which would check for lessons first before deciding to `attach` or `updateExistingPivot`.

Comment: It gives me `Trying to get property of non-object` for the `attach` line. I think the `where` clause is a bit strange. This will check for the `id` column to be equal to `lessonID`, but this is not the case. I have updated the question to clarify what the table should look like.